# save each line from csv to new file with filename as the string contained in a specific column

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a csv file on a Linux machine like this:

```
value1 value2 name  
1      2      a  
2      3      b  
4      5      c
```

What I want is to split the `n` entries in this csv into `n` text files with just the corresponding numbers in that file separated by space. N is determined by the value in name.

So above csv would become:

- `a.txt` containing `1 2`
- `b.txt` containing `2 3`
- `c.txt` containing `4 5`

In case there are multiple entries for a particular `name` then those should go together to one file.

Ex if there was

```
1  2  a   
21 31 a
```

then there should be a single `a.txt` with

```
1  2     
21 31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually

```
awk '{print $1, $2 > $3 ".txt"}' file.csv
```

You should only run into to trouble if there will be more than about one thousand new files

Comment: Why will >1k files be a problem? I just tested it with `perl -le 'for(0..10000){print "a$_ b$_ $_"}' > file; awk '{print $1, $2 > $3 ".txt"}' file` and that created 10001 files with no complaint.

Comment: do $1 $2 $3 refer to the columns? 
I have only 70 files as of now.

Comment: In case they are not `space` separated but `comma` separated values in the csv , how do I address it in the awk script? thank you in advance.

Comment: @terdon, what is your `ulimit -n`? awk should not be able to open more files than that.

Comment: @kRazzyR, then you tell awk what the input and output field separators are: `awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","; OFS = ","} {print $1,$2 > $3".txt"}' file` -- or more tersely `awk -F, '{print $1,$2 > $3".txt"}' OFS=, file`